# How to get a substring of a certain character followed by a number?

Tags: java, string

In Java, how would I get a substring of a certain character followed by a number?

The string looks like this:

```
To be, or not to be. (That is the question.) (243)
```

I want the substring up until the (243), where the number inside the parenthesis is always changing every time I call.

Comment: Could there be numbers elsewhere in the string?

Comment: You mean the regular expression `\((\d+)\)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
newstr = str.replaceFirst("\(\d+\)", "");
```

What this means is to find a substring beginning with (, then any number of digits, and then the character ). Then replace the substring with the empty string, "".

Reference: [java.lang.String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I didn't realize that the String class had built-in methods (in this case called replaceFirst) that recognized a regular expressions.  This is the answer I was really looking for.

Comment: I think you might want to anchor your regular expression to the end of the line using $ in case there happens to be a parenthesized number in your string, like `There are four (4) lights! (345)`

Answer (score 0):

You could match it with a regex, and get the index of the regex. Then use that to get the index in the string.

An example of that is [Can Java String.indexOf() handle a regular expression as a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194310/can-string-indexof-handle-a-regular-expression-as-a-parameter)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.start());//this will give you index
}
```

Comment: I'll try this.  Thanks, it looks like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "To be, or not to be. (That is the question.) (243)";
String newString = s.replaceAll("\\(\\d+\\).*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can actually just do something like:

```
mystring.substring(0,mystring.lastIndexOf"("))
```

assuming that the last thing on the line will be the number in parentheses.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need to escape the `(` in quotes there or not -- you could also specify it as a `char` rather than a string, which may be more efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop and add the characters before the number to a separate string

```
String sentence = "To be, or not to be. (That is the question.) (243)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String subSentence = getSubsentence(sentence);
}

public String getSubsentence(String sentence) {
    String subSentence = "";
    boolean checkForNum = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (checkForNum) {
            if (isInteger(sentence.getSubstring(i, i+1))) return subSentence;
            checkForNum = false;
        } else {
            if (sentence.getSubstring(i, i+1).equals("(")) checkForNum = true;
            else subSentence += sentence.getSubstring(i, i+1);
        }
    }
    return subSentence;
}

public boolean isInteger(String s) {
try { 
    Integer.parseInt(s); 
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false; 
}
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex this can be solved with.

```
public class RegExParser {

    public String getTextPart(String s) {

        String pattern = "^(\\D+)(\\s\\(\\d+\\))$";

        String part = s.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");
        return part;

    }
}
```

Simple and performance is good.