# how to Split name file to count series in java?

Tags: java, split

i have a list of files in this form:

```
name_of_file_001.csv
name_of_file_002.csv    
name_of_file_123.csv
or
name_of_file.csv
second_name_of_file.csv
```

i don't know if the file has 001 or not.
how to take name of file (only name_of_file) in java?

Comment: I dont really have the time to write a working answer right now, but have you considered checking with regular expressions? for instance smth like `[a-z]*(?=[0-9]{3})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved the problem in this mode:

```
nameOfFile.split("\\.")[0].replaceall("_[0-9]*","");
```

split("\.")[0] remove ".csv" `name_of_file_001.csv => name_of_file_001`
.replaceall("_[0-9]*","") "remove, if there is, "_001" `name_of_file_001 => name_of_file`

the result is the name of file only

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
int i=0;
while(!fullName.charAt(i).equals('.')&&!fullName.charAt(i).equals('0')){
  i++;
}
String name=fullName.substring(0, i);
```

Take the string from the beginning of the `fullName` to the first appearance of `.` or `0`.

**EDIT:**

Referring to the comments and the case of high numbers greater than `1..` and inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194331/3669624):

```
    int i=0;
    String patternStr = "[0-9\.]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fullName);
    if(matcher.find()){
     i=matcher.start();  //this will give you the first index of the regex
    }
    String name=fullName.substring(0, i);
```

**EDIT2:**

In the case where there's no Extension and the fullname doesn't match the regex(there's no numbers):

```
if(matcher.find()){
     i=matcher.start();  //this will give you the first index of the regex
}else {
 i=fullname.length();
}
String name=fullName.substring(0, i);
```

Or simply we will take all the name.

Comment: there is a possibility that the numbering is high (e.g. name_of_file_142.csv)

Comment: @mmxx yes good point, well in that case we just add this test `!fullName.charAt(i).equals('1')`.

Comment: What about numbers starting with 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ?

Comment: What about filenames that don't have an extension?

Comment: @EldadMor what about them? the name will be taken either it has an extension or not.

Comment: Well, you'll fly high on file name like "abc"

Comment: No, the filename in all cases contains the `.` mark.

Comment: Yes, I know it is a valid name, in that case if there's no extension and there's no match for the regex we just need to set the `i`var to the length of the **fullname**.

Answer (score 1):

I modified chsdk's solution with respect to mmxx's comment:

```
int i=0;
while(i < fullName.length() && ".0123456789".indexOf(fullName.charAt(i)) == -1) {
  i++;
}
String name=fullName.substring(0, i);
```

**EDIT:**
Added

```
i < fullName.length()
```

Answer (score 0):

This little class solves the problem for all the examples shown in main:

```
public class Example {

   private static boolean isNaturalNumber(String str)
   {
     return str.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
   }

   public static String getFileName(String s) {
        String fn = s.split("\\.")[0];
        int idx = fn.lastIndexOf('_');
        if (idx < 0) {
            return fn;
        }
        String lastPart = fn.substring(idx+1);
        System.out.println("last part = " + lastPart);
        if (isNaturalNumber(lastPart)) {
            return fn.substring(0,idx);
        } else {
            return fn;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(getFileName("file_name_001.csv"));
        System.out.println(getFileName("file_name_1234.csv"));
        System.out.println(getFileName("file_name.csv"));
        System.out.println(getFileName("file_name"));
        System.out.println(getFileName("file"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Replaced the exception-based check with a regex check.

**EDIT 2:** Handling file names without any underscores.

Comment: Relying on exceptions in regular execution flow isn't good programming practice.

Comment: That depends on the times you need to call this function. See here for alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java