# Find index of a non-digit using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

This is probably an easy question but I haven't been able to figure it out. I want to find the next letter (A to Z) in a string after a certain point in the string. The result I want from below is for the string money to be "$5. 00" but num2 always comes up as -1.

```
String text = "hello$5. 00Bla bla words that don't matter"

int num1 = text.indexOf('$');
int num2 = text.indexOf("[a-zA-Z]" , num1 + 1); // Always results in -1

String money = text.substring(num1, num2);
```

Comment: `String::indexOf` does not take regex as its paramater

Comment: String indexOf never takes regex as the parameter, it should be another string or char(unicode codepoint) You should be using replaceAll() here.

Comment: See proposed solutions to a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194310/can-java-string-indexof-handle-a-regular-expression-as-a-parameter)

Comment: Your specification could be clearer. It looks like what you want is really the first alphabetic character, since the dot and the space are non-digit characters.

Answer (score 1):

To find the first letter following a `$` dollar sign, using regex, you can use the following regex:

```regex
\$\P{L}*\p{L}
```

Explanation:

```
\$       Match a $ dollar sign
\P{L}*   Match 0 or more characters that are not Unicode letters
\p{L}    Match a Unicode letter
```

The index of the letter is then the last character of the matched substring, i.e. one character before the [`end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#end--) of the match.

*Example*

```
String text = "hello$5. 00Bla bla words that don't matter";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\P{L}*\\p{L}").matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    int idx = m.end() - 1;
    System.out.println("Letter found at index " + idx + ": '" + text.substring(idx) + "'");
}
```

*Output*

```
Letter found at index 11: 'Bla bla words that don't matter'
```

---

*UPDATE*

It seems the actual question was slightly different than answered above, so to capture the text from `$` dollar sign (inclusive) and all following characters up to first letter (exclusive) or end of string, use this regex:

```regex
\$\P{L}*
```

*Example*

```
String text = "hello$5. 00Bla bla words that don't matter";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\P{L}*").matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
    String money = m.group();
    System.out.println("money = \"" + money + "\"");
}
```

*Output*

```
money = "$5. 00"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, as my workstation isn't set up for Java 9, but using that release, you should be able to do this:

```
String result = text.substring(text.indexOf('$'), text.length())
    .takeWhile(ch -> !Character.isAlphabetic(ch))
    .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

`result` will evaluate to `$5. 00`

Note: `Stream<T>#takeWhile` is a Java 9 feature

Comment: and then how do you use `index`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for the comment, I was mainly focused on the title question, but I edited my answer to focus on the rest of the question.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help everyone. I found a way to do this without using regex.

```
String money = "";
while (!Character.isLetter(text.charAt(num1))) {
  money = money + text.charAt(num1);
  num1++;
}
```

It might need some work later but it seems to work.

Comment: Hmm, so much for helping you.  Anyway, what happens with the `'` char?  Hopw do you handle the `$`?

Comment: I kept the int num1 = text.indexOf('$'); Explaining that regex wouldn't work with indexof was actually a huge help.

Comment: @ScaryWombat hahahahahhahaha